# how to add double quote to a string in Perl

Tags: perl

my code looks following:

`$id = "PROD121213123";`

I am passing  this to a function and adding this to it

`"\"$wi_id\""`

where $wi_id looks like `my $wi_id = $_`

After `"\"$wi_id\""`  the value looks like "PROD121213123" which I checked in Eclipse debugger (using EPIC)

I am calling curl.exe from Perl and it looks like this "" is omitted during execution. How can I have "" to the string and still execute using CURL?

Comment: Please post some code, the explanation is confusing.

Comment: What precisely makes you think that the quotes are omitted during execution?

Comment: I get shivers when I try to think what the OP may be trying to do.

Comment: i wanted to add double quotes for value of $wi_id

Comment: use LWP instead of `system "curl..."`; problem solved.

Comment: I am using RATLPERL and not perl and its not so easy to compile the perl packages for that. Hence I am using curl

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing the equivalent of

```
my $id = "\"PROD121213123\"";    # String <<"PROD121213123">>
system "curl.exe ... $id ...";   # curl sees <<PROD121213123>>
```

It's because the quotes have special meaning to the "shell". Command line parsing is a bit of a mess in Windows (nothing to do with Perl), so you might not be able to even pass double-quotes to `curl`. I'd try using the multiple arg version of `system`.

Comment: my url should look like following: `http://localhost/olsc/context/workitems?oslc_cm=id="PROD121213123"` I am trying to build the url in perl code along with `"PROD121213123"`

Comment: @Karthik Krishnan, That's not a valid URL. `"` is not allowed unescaped in URLs. Furthermore, the `=` in the value should really be escaped. I'd use `use URI; my $url = URI->new('http://localhost/olsc/context/workitems'); $url->query_form(oslc_cm => qq{id="$id"});` unless the code that processes the URL is to buggy to handle the proper URL.

Comment: ... `system qq{curl.exe ... "$url" ...};`

Comment: I am using Backticks and system.

Comment: @Karthik Krishnan, What does that mean?

Comment: @Karthik Krishnan, Everything you've said to date is extremely unclear. Please spend some more effort.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to pass a quotes string to a command which is called though a shell. To accomplice that, you'll need to escape the quotes to hide them for the shell:

```
my $id = q(\"PRD121212\");
system qq(curl.exe ... $id ...);
```

HTH,
Paul